# Найти общие элементы в массиве

Tags: массивы, mysql

Есть запросы которые выдают таблицу вида. id и много строк
нужно каким то образом найти получить запрос с общими id из этих запросом

то есть допустим 3 запроса
id
1
2
3

id
2
5
6

id
4
1
2
7
8

должен быть результат
id
2

PS прямо в запросе, конечно же.

Comment: В какой среде обрабатываються результаты запросов?
Или вы каким-то образом хотите прямо в запросе это сделать?

Comment: какой то не совсем понятный вопрос

Answer (score 1):

вот проблема то.

```
SELECT t1.id FROM t1,t2 WHERE t1.id=t2.id;
```

Подучите SQL